# Finding repeated cell

Tags: sql

Assume we have a table for movies (title, year, director, genre) that title and year are identity.

Why for find repeated titles this query is wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT title
FROM movies m1, movies m2
WHERE m1.title = m2.title AND m1.year != m2.year
```

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong syntactically because `title` is not qualified so the reference cannot be disambiguated.

It is wrong colloquially because you are using archaic `join` syntax.

It is possibly wrong logically, because it does not find duplicates within a year.

I suggest simple aggregation:

```
SELECT m.title
FROM movies m
GROUP BY m.title
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

You can add `AND MIN(m.year) <> MAX(m.year)` if you really do want them in different years.